# Exert Ability Workings with Untap Abilities

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My main question is can you exert a creature twice in the same turn?

For example, if I were to attack with and exert [Champion of Rhonas](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChampion%20of%20Rhonas%5d), then activate [Aggravated Assault](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAggravated%20Assault%5d)'s ability to untap and attack again, would I then be able to exert again giving me the ability to put another creature on the field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can Exert a permanent multiple times in the same turn like this. The rules on Exert very helpfully clarify this:

> 701.37. Exert
>
> - 701.37a To exert a permanent, you choose to have it not untap during your next untap step.
> - **701.37b A permanent can be exerted even if it’s not tapped or has already been exerted in a turn.** If you exert a permanent more than once before your next untap step, each effect causing it not to untap expires during the same untap step.
> - (and a couple of other lines)

Very conveniently for us, all the Exerts only apply to the very next untap step. We won't have any Exerts "lagging behind", they all wear off simultaneously.

Comment: This is brilliant news... I have been avoiding this ability for too long haha

Comment: @ThunderToes Keep in mind that this means Exert has some pretty good synergy with Vigilance, since you can exert without ever tapping the creatures in the first place.

Comment: @Malco Which is a big part of why the design space for Amonkhet block had so little Vigilance, they intentionally avoided the exert abuse.

Comment: @Malco Thats very sneaky but I like it haha now to find some enchantments/equipment that gives my exert creatures vigilance...

Comment: @ThunderToes goodluck, though assuming you are playing standard there isn't much out there for giving creatures vigilance. But [here is every standard legal card with vigillance](https://scryfall.com/search?q=f%3Astandard+o%3Avigilance) to get you started.